# Creating an event for certain weekdays

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I want the user to choose on which weekdays they want to repeat a certain event, so far I implemented a weekdaychooser similar to the one from the Alarm Clock, but now I am thinking about how to store this data in Core Data. Should I create a BOOL attribute for everyday and how is the best way to get an array of, let's say thursdays, in a certain timespan?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bitfield for this repeat pattern (bit per day).
You can get an array of 'Thursdays' repeating events by setting a predicate:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((repeatPattern & %@) != 0) AND (...timespan limitations...)",@(ThursdayBit)]`